# How can I filter to only null/empty dates in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and using the jqGrid to display tabular data.  In one of my grid displays I show recipe data and there are a couple of date columns where I don't always have a date for the data.

Using the date picker I can filter to things that have a particular date or happen before/after a particular date.  But how can I filter to things that are missing a date?  The workaround I'm using right now is to sort the date column and that'll get me easily enough to the missing dates but I'd like to be able to easily answer the question "How many recipes are missing the last prepared date?"

Any ideas for this?

Comment: Which filtering you use: toolbar filtering, advanced searching filter or both of these?

Comment: @Oleg - both, but toolbar is specifically what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: How you imagine to distinguish "no filter on the date" from "NULL (missing a date) in the date" in case of usage the toolbar filtering?

Comment: @Oleg - I don't really know how that's supposed to work, quite honestly.  Not even sure it's possible.  I'd considered an additional column that was a bool indicator but that seems clumsy.

Comment: You can use some special value like `NULL` to search for missing (NULL) values. Your server code will analyse the input for the NULL value and make IS NULL in the corresponding SQL SELECT. The main problem is just to suggest the interface which will be **intuitive**, so that every user will be able to use the spacial NULL value without any education in the subject "How to use the GUI of your program".

Comment: I tried using a space character to represent empty data and then have a select box in the filter toolbar with a value of ' ' (space).  This worked except I noticed some weirdness (only in IE...something about how space characters are processed?) when using inline row editing when restoring/editing data- when filtering to ' ' (space), the edited/restored data (with space character) was not displayed.